# Scrape sub classes under div class in Python and BeaufifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scraping from a page for the houses listed, including addresses, beds & baths, and prices. The html of the relevant information on the page looks the following.

[image]

I have the following python codes with BeautifulSoup.

I first defined the class to be included is `bottomV2`, which should include all required information.

However, the `price` is not a `div` class but a `span` class under `div` class. And the beds/bath information is listed in three separated `div` class.

How should I modify my code to capture the prices and beds&baths?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "https://www.redfin.com/city/2749/VT/Burlington"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

houses = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

homes = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'bottomV2'})

for row in homes:
    house = {}
    house['url'] = "www.redfin.com"+row.a['href']
    house['address'] = row.a['title'].split(', ')[0]
    house['city'] = row.a['title'].split(', ')[1]
    house['state'] = row.a['title'].split(' ')[-2]
    house['zip_code'] = str(row.a['title'].split(' ')[-1])
    houses.append(house)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses `zip()` built-in function to get stats, link and price together. Then parses the stats and link text for additional information:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.redfin.com/city/2749/VT/Burlington'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print('{:<10}{:<11}{:<20}{:<30}{:<15}{:<10}{:<10}{:<15}{}'.format('Beds', 'Baths', 'Sq.m.', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Code', 'Price', 'Link'))
for stats, link, price in zip(soup.select('.HomeStatsV2'),
                              soup.select('.bottomV2 > a'),
                              soup.select('.homecardV2Price')):

    beds, baths, sqm = map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), stats.select('div'))
    address, city, code = link.text.split(',')
    state, code = code.split()
    price = price.text
    link = 'https://www.redfin.com' + link['href']

    print('{:<10}{:<11}{:<20}{:<30}{:<15}{:<10}{:<10}{:<15}{}'.format(beds, baths, sqm, address, city, state, code, price, link) )
```

Prints:

```
Beds      Baths      Sq.m.               Address                       City           State     Code      Price          Link
4 Beds    4 Baths    4,970 Sq. Ft.       1 Crescent Beach Dr            Burlington    VT        05401     $1,595,000     https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/1-Crescent-Beach-Dr-05408/home/91176261
2 Beds    1 Bath     864 Sq. Ft.         208 Sandra Cir                 Burlington    VT        05408     $275,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/208-Sandra-Cir-05408/home/91180546
1 Bed     1 Bath     688 Sq. Ft.         91 Hildred Dr                  Burlington    VT        05401     $147,500       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/91-Hildred-Dr-05401/unit-91/home/91178740
3 Beds    1 Bath     896 Sq. Ft.         77 VENUS Ave                   Burlington    VT        05408     $203,200       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/77-Venus-Ave-05408/home/91175236
2 Beds    2 Baths    1,423 Sq. Ft.       40 College St Unit 211D        Burlington    VT        05401     $559,900       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/40-College-St-05401/unit-211D/home/91182093
2 Beds    1 Bath     1,229 Sq. Ft.       191 S Winooski Ave #1          Burlington    VT        05401     $425,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/191-S-Winooski-Ave-05401/unit-1/home/91183775
2 Beds    3 Baths    3,270 Sq. Ft.       15 Eastman Way                 Burlington    VT        05401     $1,950,000     https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/15-Eastman-Way-05401/home/91182784
4 Beds    1.5 Baths  1,520 Sq. Ft.       63 Birch Ct                    Burlington    VT        05408     $399,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/63-Birch-Ct-05408/home/91178132
2 Beds    1.75 Baths 1,680 Sq. Ft.       267 Pearl St Unit A3           Burlington    VT        05401     $365,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/267-Pearl-St-05401/unit-A3/home/91182306
4 Beds    1.75 Baths 1,420 Sq. Ft.       32 Vine St                     Burlington    VT        05408     $429,900       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/32-Vine-St-05408/home/91181276
4 Beds    4 Baths    4,100 Sq. Ft.       62 Overlake Park               Burlington    VT        05401     $1,545,000     https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/62-Overlake-Park-05401/home/91183380
4 Beds    2.75 Baths 2,008 Sq. Ft.       61 Muirfield Rd                Burlington    VT        05408     $510,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/61-Muirfield-Rd-05408/home/91180706
1 Bed     1 Bath     1,033 Sq. Ft.       40 College St #209             Burlington    VT        05401     $359,500       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/40-College-St-05401/unit-209/home/171717430
2 Beds    1.5 Baths  690 Sq. Ft.         131 Main St #306               Burlington    VT        05401     $309,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/131-Main-St-05401/unit-306/home/63520198
2 Beds    1 Bath     598 Sq. Ft.         24 Avenue B                    Burlington    VT        05408     $44,900        https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/24-Avenue-B-05408/home/91185051
—Beds     —Baths     —Sq. Ft.            227 S Cove Rd                  Burlington    VT        05401     $300,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/227-S-Cove-Rd-05401/home/171490078
1 Bed     1 Bath     744 Sq. Ft.         131 Main St #504               Burlington    VT        05401     $265,000       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/131-Main-St-05401/unit-504/home/91183359
4 Beds    2.5 Baths  2,715 Sq. Ft.       75 Brookes Ave                 Burlington    VT        05401     $669,900       https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/75-Brookes-Ave-05401/home/91182294
—Beds     —Baths     10,240 Sq. Ft.      71-73 Elmwood Ave              Burlington    VT        05401     $2,150,000     https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/71-Elmwood-Ave-05401/unit-87-91/home/95080381
—Beds     8 Baths    4,491 Sq. Ft.       57-59 Buell St                 Burlington    VT        05401     $1,325,000     https://www.redfin.com/VT/Burlington/57-Buell-St-05401/home/95080294
```